# Load a different file based on which ListView I select, using only one WebView

Tags: android

I am trying to use a `ListView` to open different files based on what I select using only one `WebView`.

I have the intents set up:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  switch (position) {
  case '0' :
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tabViewerClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

And in the `tabViewerClass` I have this:

```
WebView tabViewing = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
tabViewing.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/twentyseven.html");
```

the second line `tabViewing.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/twentyseven.html");` I want to be called when I select `case 0`, but if I select a different option I want it to call another file in my `WebView`.

Something like this:

```
case '0' :
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tabViewerClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    load whatever file
case '1' :
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tabViewerClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    load a different file in the webview
case '2' :
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tabViewerClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    load a different file in webview
```

`load whatever file` doing the equivalent of    `tabViewing.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/twentyseven.html");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass filename as extra inside your intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tabViewerClass.class);
i.putExtra("filename", "file:///android_asset/twentyseven.html");
startActivity(i);
```

and inside tabViewerClass:

```
String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");
WebView tabViewing = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
tabViewing.loadUrl(filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another means to pass the file you want to load is to use a Uri.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tabViewerClass.class);
i.setData(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/twentyseven.html"));
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the webview you can load the page by retrieving the uri

```
WebView tabViewing = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
tabViewing.loadUrl(getIntent().getDataString());
```

Both ways will achieve what you want.